# Adjust columns in Hexl-Mode?

Tags: hexl-mode

By default, it looks like hexl-mode shows 16-bytes per row as the column numbers range from 0x0 - 0xf.

Is there a way to adjust how many byte are displayed per row?  E.g. 8-byes per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see such an option in `hexl.el`, no.

You can do that in [nhexl-mode](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nhexl-mode.html), OTOH: just set the `nhexl-line-width` variable accordingly (or set it to `t` which lets it adjust to your window width).